# Storing OTP seeds in password manager

Tags: password-management, one-time-password, keepass, totp

I am storing my passwords in a password manager (keepass). Also I am using keepass to set up one-time passwords for some accounts. Keepass is storing the seeds of the OTP's in its database.

If my keepass DB is compromised I am losing my passwords plus my OTP seeds.

Is the OTP adding extra security in this case? Or do I need to store the seed separately to get extra security?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, OTP is adding extra security. If a hacker gets your password by guessing or shoulder surfing, your account with no OTP is doomed. If you have OTP for your account, the hacker still cannot break into your account, even if he got one OTP code before.

If you keep OTP seed separately in a well-designed app, it is more secure. But if you put them in some cloud-based app without end-to-end encryption, I doubt.

Comment: Yeah... I dropped 1Password after 20 years when they went to cloud-only.  My passwords are the *last* thing I'm going to store in Some Else's Cloud